# Bloomberg API and specifying preferred order of pricing sources

Tags: bloomberg

Is there any way within Bloomberg API to specify a preferred ordering of pricing sources through API call? By using PCS, you can specify the terminal preferred pricing sources, however I want to programatically make this call through the API.

Current you can specify something like this to explicitly specify a pricing source:

```
MSFT@ETPX US Equity
```

However, can something like this be done?

```
MSFT@ETPX&MSPE&ANOTHER...ETC US Equity
```

Comment: I'm sure you have already considered this but you could subscribe to all the PCS and programmatically define your source priority.

Comment: How can I programmatically define pricing source priority?

Comment: Have you tried just asking bloomberg? You're paying enough for the service and support.

Comment: Yes, haven't received an answer from them yet.

Answer (score 2):

The users preferences will be honoured by the API call.  So if you do not specify the pricing source, everything will work as expected.  This is also respected by any per security datalicense requests made against that linked account.

Whether or not this is a good thing is open to debate, we used to advise everyone to never change the default settings.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I realize that. The question asks whether or not there is an ability to specify them programatically in the single request string. This would be to prevent the possibility that a user changing there PCS settings would change the pricing sources of an application using the API.

Comment: There isn't, the only option you have is to query every pricing source you're interested in and pick a value yourself, as described by assylias

Answer (score 0):

You could define your priority programmatically (pseudo code):

```
function getPrice(ticker) {

    if (getPrice("MSFT@ETPX US Equity") != null) return getPrice("MSFT@ETPX US Equity");
    elseif (getPrice("MSFT@MSPE US Equity") != null) return getPrice("MSFT@MSPE US Equity");

    ....
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a single command that would allow me to set priority, just as a user can set priority through PCS<GO>. I realize that I can make multiple calls and compare them.